# How to download Google drive form programmatically?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am trying to download/Export the "Google Form" created in Google Drive. Google Drive APIs usualy gives "ExportLinks" to download any Google Drive file types. In case of Google Forms, Google drive SDK API is not returning any "ExportLinks" or "DownloadUrl" for the mimetype "application/vnd.google-apps.form".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working as intended. You cannot get downloadLink for any of Google Docs/Spreadsheet/etc. You can find list of supported exportLink from [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads?hl=en), which doesn't seem to support Google Form. There is no way to download Google Drive Form from API.

Comment: Thanks:) "There is no way to download Google Drive Form from API" is this confirmed?

Comment: Based on information from the documentation, yes. No guarantee, tough.

Comment: Correct Sir. Even I had arrived to same conclusion before posting the question. I just wanted to confirm that anywhere google has explicitly mentioned it. Thanks :)